# mypy Incompatible return value type with TypeVar(bound=str)

Tags: python, mypy, typing

```py
T = TypeVar("T", bound=str)


def foo(a: T, b: T) -> T:
    return a + b


print(foo("1", "2"))
```

mypy:
`error: Incompatible return value type (got "str", expected "T")  [return-value]`

I dont understand how to fix this problem(using bound).

Comment: There's nothing to fix here - the error is correct. The `__add__` method of subclasses of `str` do not return instances of the subclass; you can verify this at runtime (`class A(str): pass`; `print(type(A() + A()))`). Therefore, the return type can't be `-> T`, it has to be `-> str`.